# How can I use TaggedValues within a DDL script?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'd like to generate table creation code for my data model. This works great, I have changed the default DDL templates.

Now I have a feature which can be set or not for a table (TemporalTable). This in turn will generate different DDL (sql) code based on the TaggedValue value.

How can I access a TaggedValue from a table within the DDL template script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is described in the help [here](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.0/model_domains/ddl_property_macros.html)

For a user defined tagged value on a table that would be:

> **tableUserProperty:"propertyName"** 
>   Returns the value for the
>   user-defined property in the repository's version of the current
>   Table.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - propertyName - the property name that is to be retrieved
>
> **Remarks**
>
> None.

Comment: Almost correct! It's %tableUserProperty:"NameOfTaggedValue"%. the tableBoolProperty does not return values from taggedValues ;)